# Rasterizing a Vector Layer using GDAL lib in Python

Tags: python, gdal, qgis

I'm trying to rasterize vector layer using the explanation found in [Rasterizing a GDAL layer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2220749/rasterizing-a-gdal-layer). I would like to create a raster layer from a DEM, which contains the data of a particular field of the vector. (The field is named "Index"). To do that, I use,

```
err = gdal.RasterizeLayer(
    target_ds,
    (3,2,1),
    source_layer,
    burn_values=(0,0,0),
    options=["ATTRIBUTE= Index"]
)
```

But the result is a raster with all zeros.

I'm sure it's a problem with the parameters, but I don't understand what's wrong with them or how to fix it. Any suggestion?

Comment: still looking for help?

Answer (score 1):

You are burning zeros onto a zero background. Change the burn value to something other than zero.